# Pinching of an ODE on a simple Lie algebra

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a real simple Lie algebra with the positive definite Killing metric $(\cdot,\cdot)$. Let $R\in Sym^2(\mathfrak g)$ be a self-adjoint operator $R\colon \mathfrak g\to\mathfrak g$. Define self-adjoint operator $R^\#$ as
$$
(R^\#x,x):=\sum_{i,j}([Re_i,R e_j],x)([e_i,e_j],x),
$$
where $\{e_i\}^{\dim\mathfrak g}_{i=1}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathfrak g$.

In coordinates it can be defined as
$$
(R^\#)^{i j}=c_{mn}^i c_{ps}^j R^{mp}R^{ns},
$$
where the summation convention is used.

Studying certain metric flows on homogeneous manifolds I came across the following ODE for $R$:
$$
\partial_t R=R^\#.
$$

I would like to know the answer to the following question.

**Question.** Assume that at the initial moment the operator $R=R(0)$ is positive, i.e, $(Rx,x)>0$ for all nonzero $x\in \mathfrak g$. Solution to the ODE in this case exist only up to some time $t_{max}$ and $\lim_{t\to t_{max}}|R(t)|^2=+\infty$. Is it true that $R(t)$ pinch towards the identity operator $Id$, i.e.,
$$
\lim_{t\to t_{max}} R(t)/|R(t)|=Id?
$$

Or one might ask a simpler question: what are scale-static solutions of this equation, i.e., positive operators satisfying
$$
\lambda R=R^\#
$$
for a positive constant $\lambda$?

**Background and motivation.** Similar ODE appeared before in the study of Ricci flow. Operation $R^\#$ was first introduced in [H]. In [BW] authors consider ODE $\partial_t R=R^2+R^\#$ and prove that for $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak{so}(n)$ and for $R$ satisfying Bianchi identities positive operators pinch towards the identity. Their proof heavily exploits decomposition of $Sym^2(\mathfrak{so}(n))$ into irreducible components. See also [B] for the study of the same ODE.

[H] Hamilton, R.: Four-manifolds with positive curvature operator. J. Differ. Geom. 24(2), 153–179 (1986)

[BW] Böhm, C., Wilking, B.: Manifolds with positive curvature operators are space forms. Ann. Math. (2) 167(3), 1079–1097 (2008)

[B] Bhattacharya, A.: On the curvature ODE associated to the Ricci flow. Geom Dedicata. 175:189–209 (2015)